# split data row wise based on row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores information in the below format.

[image]

id, value , property are the columns. I have a requirement now to sum up data  based on property.

i.e for property column F2 and Value,

I need values summed up and displayed as below:

```
Type | Sum
Cars   |  1892+702+515 
Bikes  | 1393 +0 + 474.6
```

Note: I know this is not the way to store data in a table, but table alterations are currently not possible.

Appreciate if you  could give your inputs on this.

Comment: how would you know which values correspond to which property?

Comment: or else some query that splits data into 2 tables, 1 for bikes and one for cars, this would also help.

Comment: @vkp , you see the value F2 in property column, the value that corresponds to this are the basis on which i should split the table.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a really bad design.  It looks like you are using the positions in the table to assign "groupings".  Fortunately, you have an `id` column, so this is possible to do in SQL.

Here is the idea:  First assign the appropriate `F2` property to each row.  Then do an aggregation.  This following uses `outer apply` for the first part and `group by` for the second:

```
select t2.value,
       sum(case when isnumeric(t.value) = 1 then cast(t.value as decimal(10, 2))
           end) as thesum
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.id <= t.id and t2.property = 'F2'
      order by t2.id desc
     ) t2
group by t2.value;
```

This doesn't filter out the first group (all 0's).  You can do that with an additional `WHERE` clause if you like.

Comment: thank you for the help but I get the output like this                                          value     | thesum
0            |  1867.6
BIKES   | NULL
Cars      | 3109.00                   sorry this is not formatted properl

Comment: Sorry for the comment above, the results are not properly formatted.

Comment: @MichaelKovattil . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  I think this version should work -- once the references to `t1` are fixed.

Comment: Hey, It works fine. Thank you for this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution which uses LEAD in case if you are running SQL Server 2012+ (note my comments).

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourtable 
TABLE 
(
  id       int identity primary key, -- emulate an index on ID 
  value    varchar(100), 
  property varchar(5)
);

INSERT @yourtable (value, property) VALUES 
('0',     'F2'),
('0',     'V1'),
('0',     'V2'),
('0',     'V3'),
('Cars',  'F2'),
('1892',  'V1'),
('702',   'V2'),
('515',   'V3'),
('Bikes', 'F2'),
('1393',  'V1'),
('0',     'V2'),
('474.6', 'V2');

-- Solution
WITH startPoints AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)
  FROM @yourtable 
),
groups AS
(
  SELECT value, rn, ttl = 
    ISNULL(LEAD(id,1) OVER (ORDER BY id), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @yourtable)+1) - (rn+1)
  FROM startPoints
  WHERE property = 'F2' AND value LIKE ('%[^0-9.]%')
)
SELECT
  value, 
  SUM = 
  (
    SELECT SUM(CAST(value AS decimal(10,2)))
    FROM startPoints s
    WHERE s.rn BETWEEN g.rn+1 AND g.rn+ttl
  )
FROM groups g;
```